# Linq in from ObservableCollection in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I am tring to get the value "thisValueIwant". Is there any possibility to get this value so easy? Or Maybe there is another solution for these 2 ObservableCollection

```
public class Foo
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FooInFoo> Details { get; set; }
}

public class FooInFoo
{
    public string thisValueIwant { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Foo> FooCollection = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();

        FooCollection.Add(new Foo{
            number =1,
            Details = new ObservableCollection<FooInFoo>{ new FooInFoo {thisValueIwant = "very important string"}}
        });

        string x = (from f in FooCollection
                    where f.number == 1
                    select ???)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ObservableCollection<FooInFoo> Details` is a collection, you have to decide which details you want: the first, last, any or all.

Assuming you want the first:

```
var d = FooCollection.Where(f => f.Number == 1).FirstOrDefault()?.Details.FirstOrDefault()?.thisValueIwant;
```

Or the last:

```
var d = FooCollection.Where(f => f.Number == 1).FirstOrDefault()?.Details.LastOrDefault()?.thisValueIwant;
```

Or all (materialized as an array):

```
var ds = FooCollection.Where(f => f.Number == 1).FirstOrDefault()?.Details.Select(d => d.thisValueIwant).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your answer is logic, but I get a error, that "details" is not a Member of"FooCollection" This one works for me now:`string x = (from f in FooCollection
                        where f.number == 1
                        select f.Details[0].thisValueIwant).FirstOrDefault();` thanks for your response

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Missed that. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

An `ObservableCollection<T>` is a `Collection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Therefore the fact that your `FooCollection` is an observable collection is not important, you can regard it as a sequence of `Foo`, an `IEnumerable<Foo>` and equally an `IEnumerable<FooInFoo>`

Your code will be like (sorry, I only know how to write in Method format)
In baby steps:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> AllFooWithNumber1 = FooCollection
   .Where(foo => foo.Number == 1);
```

If you are certain there is exactly one continue with:

```
Foo fooWithNumber1 = AllFooWithNumber1.Single();
```

Consider using [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are not certain that there is one.

Once you have the Foo that you want, you can select the Details:

```
IEnumerable<FooInFoo> detailsOfFooWithNumber1 = fooWithNumber1.Details;
FooInFoo detailIWant = detailsOfFooWithNumber1
   .Where(detail => some expression that uses detail...)
   .SingleOrDefault();

string thisValueIWant = defailtIWant.thisValueIWant;
```

Or in one statement:

```
string thisValueIWant = FooCollection
   .Where(foo => foo.Number == 1)
   .Single()
   .Details
   .Where(detail => ...)
   .Single()
   .thisValueIWant;
```

Problems might arise if you are not certain there is one Single element.

If you want to check foo.Number for a given value AND all details for some predicate, consider using [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx). This is used whenever you have sequences of sequences (arrays within arrays). With SelectMany you enumerate over all these inner arrays as if it was one array:

```
IEnumerable<string> valuesIWant = FooCollection
    .Where(foo => foo.Number == 1)
    .SelectMany(foo => foo.Details)
    // now you have one sequence of all FooInFoo that are Details within
    // Foo objects with Number 1
    .Where(detail => expression that selects the FooInFoo you want)
    .Select(detail => detail.thisValueIWant);
```

Comment: I don't understand the "Where(detail=>)" in your example Code. I build it with this: `string x = FooCollection.Where(foo => foo.number == 1).Single().Details.Single().thisValueIwant;` And thanks for response

Comment: Whenever you see a Linq function with a parameter definition like Func<TSource, TKey>, then you should provide a function with input one of the Source elements of your sequence, and output a TKey. You do this using Lambda: left of the => you put a parameter name that identiefies one element of the source sequence. On the right of the => you put code that has as input this parameter and as output a TKey.  See also https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes

Answer (score 0):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library maybe. Using this library you can code like this:

```C#
Expression<Func<string>> expr = () => 
   FooCollection
      .Filtering(а => f.number == 1)
      .FirstComputing().Value
      .Using(f => f != null 
           ? f.Details.FirstComputing().Using(fif => 
               fif.Value != null ? fif.Value.thisValueIwant : null).Value
           : null).Value;

Computing<string> x = expr.Computing();

// x.Value is what you want
```

x is [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) and notifies you about changes of computing result of expr. Do not forget make all properties mentioned in the code above notify of changes through the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface.